# How to compare date for MongoDB using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I'm using mongoDB library in codeigniter. I want select the data if record is present for a perticular date.
My Collection is like -

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("573c34ca68dbc73f0bef559f"),
   "attendanceDate": ISODate("2016-05-18T00:00:00.0Z"),
   "bid": "569c5360d05f2b33658136c1",
   "classid": "569c53c7d05f2b33658136c3",
   "kidid": "567a44dad05f2b6c4639bf7c",
   "isAttended": "yes" 
}
```

And i want to compare date with "attendanceDate".
I tried with -

```
$classdate = "2016-05-18";
$classdatenext = "2016-05-19";
where_arr2 = array(
"bid" => $bid,
"classid" => $classid,
"kidid" => $kid_id
);
$attendance_row = $this->mongo_db->select(array('isAttended'))->where($where_arr1)->where_gte('attendanceDate', $classdate)->where_lt('attendanceDate', $classdatenext)->get('collection_attendance');
```

Above query returning the empty array. Is there any solution to get the result ?